# Python background shell script communication

Tags: python, shell, background-process

I have 2 python scripts, `foo.py` and `bar.py`. I am running foo.py in the background using

```
python foo.py &
```

Now I want to run `bar.py` and use the stdout from this file to trigger script inside foo.py. Is this possible? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [UNIX named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) for that.

First, you create named pipe object by executing `mkfifo named_pipe` in the same directory, where you have your python files.

Your `foo.py` then could look like this:

```
while True:
    for line in open('named_pipe'):
        print 'Got: [' + line.rstrip('\n') + ']'
```

And your `bar.py` could look like this:

```
import sys

print >>open('named_pipe', 'wt'), sys.argv[-1]
```

So, you run your consumer process like this: `python foo.py &`.
And finally, each time you execute `python bar.py Hello`, you will see the message `Got: [Hello]` in your console.

UPD: unlike Paul's answer, if you use *named* pipe, you don't have to start one of the processes from inside the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system that actually comes from UNIX world that creates `pipes` between processes. A pipe is basically a pair of file descriptors, each program having access to one of them. One program writes to the pipe, while the other reads:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

However, this requires an aditional script where you start foo and bar as subprocesses and connect their outputs/inputs.